# What macro does Clang define to announce C++11 mode, if any?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

What macro does Clang define to announce C++11 mode, if any?

GCC defines `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__`, at least some versions do. MSVC seems to have the support turned on by default at least for `_MSC_VER >= 1600`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses different preprocessor tests for each separate feature, like

```
#if  __has_feature(cxx_decltype)
```

for testing if `decltype` is implemented.

See the complete list here

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checking_upcoming_features

Comment: I must admit I really like this system, I wish other compilers would *jump on the bandwagon* here. It is just so much more self-explanatory than checking against a version number.

Answer (score 2):

The standard says you can look at the value of _cplusplus to determine which standard the compiler is targeting. Although, in practice you may not be able to do much with this information. See Bo Persson's answer for a much better solution.

C++98/03 - 199711L

C++11 - 201103L

Comment: `__cplusplus = 199711L / 201103L` is only as of GCC 4.7.0 and higher, unless the patch gets backported. 4.6 and earlier use `__cplusplus = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Clang defines the same macro, mostly for compatibility with GCC's libstdc++.

I seem to remember the devs liking feature-specific checks like in libc++ [better](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/__config):

(Scroll down some)